# What does ${}^{\mathsf{T}}$ mean in the context of the binomial distribution?

Tags: regression, logistic, binomial-distribution, linear-model, notation

In a presentation of the binomial distribution on [this website](https://www.kaggle.com/avehtari/bayesian-logistic-regression-with-rstanarm), the probability of the success of a trial is presented as $\pi=g^{-1}(\eta)$, with $g$ the inverse link function. $\eta=\alpha+\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}^\mathsf{T}\beta}$ is described as a "linear predictor."

Is $^\mathsf{T}$ here the transpose symbol? If so, what does it mean in the context of a linear model? If not, what is this symbol?

Comment: It's a transpose symbol.  $x$ is a column vector, so $x^t$ is a row vector.  $x^t \beta$ is a row vector times a column vector, hence a scalar.   Thus, $x^t \beta$ is just a fancy way to write a dot product.

Answer (score 3):

What the equation is describing is not a "binomial distribution", but a generalized linear model. Such model is described in terms of linear predictor:

$$
\eta = \alpha+\boldsymbol{\mathrm{x}^\mathsf{T}\beta}
$$

link function

$$
\pi = g^{-1}(\eta)
$$

and likelihood function

$$
Y \sim \mathcal{Bernoulli}(\pi)
$$

as [described](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/347935/do-we-always-assume-cross-entropy-cost-function-for-logistic-regression-solution/347959#347959) in [multiple places](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/190763/how-to-decide-which-glm-family-to-use/303592#303592) on this site. When using Bernoulli distribution as a likelihood function, we are talking about [logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163034/bayesian-logit-model-intuitive-explanation/163039#163039).

As about the $^\mathsf{T}$ symbol, it stands for [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) (alternatively you could see $^{'}$), so it is a shortcut to saying

$$
\mathrm{a}^\mathsf{T} \mathrm{b} = a_1 b_1 + a_2 b_2 + \dots + a_k b_k
$$

where, depending on context, it could be matrix times vector, or vector times vector.